# how can i implement Gaussian noise attack in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I try to implement the code of https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07248 that is about watermarking using deep learning, but I need to apply some attacks like Gaussian noise during learning. I used GaussianNoise layer but it said it only used during training. so, I am confused this means when I want to test my network this noise layer does not work? what should I do if I want to use Gaussian noise layer? how can I implement it? I also need other attacks like cropping that I do not know how can I implement them in layers:((

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GaussianNoise,Dropout,BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AtrousConv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as Kr
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import keract
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda;
#-----------------building w train---------------------------------------------
w_expand=np.zeros((49999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wv_expand=np.zeros((9999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
wt_random=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_random=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
w_expand[:,:4,:4]=wt_random
wv_expand[:,:4,:4]=wv_random
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
wt_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_test
wt_expand=wt_expand.reshape((1,28,28,1))

#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
#conv3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e', kernel_initializer='Orthogonal',bias_initializer='glorot_uniform')(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
#DrO1=Dropout(0.25,name='Dro1')(BN)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)

#-----------------------adding watermark---------------------------------------
#add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + Kr.backend.constant(w_expand))
#encoded_merged=keras.layers.Add()([encoded,wtm])
#add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x + wtm)
#encoded_merged = add_const(encoded)
#encoder=Model(inputs=image, outputs= encoded_merged)
#encoded_merged = Concatenate(axis=3)([encoded, wtm])
add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm])
#encoder=Model(inputs=[image,wtm], outputs= encoded_merged ,name='encoder')
#encoder.summary()

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#deconv_input=Input((28,28,1),name='inputTodeconv')
#encoded_merged = Input((28, 28, 2))
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d')(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d')(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d')(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl4d')(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv3)
#DrO2=Dropout(0.25,name='DrO2')(BNd)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(BNd) 
#model=Model(inputs=image,outputs=decoded)

model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)

decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w')(decoded_noise)
convw2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2w')(convw1)
convw3 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl3w')(convw2)
convw4 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl4w')(convw3)
convw5 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl5w')(convw4)
convw6 = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl6w')(convw5)
#BNed=BatchNormalization()(convw6)
#DrO3=Dropout(0.25, name='DrO3')(BNed)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W')(convw6)  
# reconsider activation (is W positive?)
# should be filter=1 to match W
watermark_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])

watermark_extraction.summary()
#----------------------training the model--------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------Data preparation----------------------------------------

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
#opt=SGD(momentum=0.99)
watermark_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'decoder_output':'mse','reconstructed_W':'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'decoder_output': 0.1, 'reconstructed_W': 1.0},metrics=['mae'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=20)
#rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=20, min_delta=1E-4, verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_5x5F_dp_gn_add_adam.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history=watermark_extraction.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=200,
          batch_size=32, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], [x_validation,wv_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='E:/concatnatenetwork', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False),es,mc])
watermark_extraction.summary()
WEIGHTS_FNAME = 'v1_adam_model_5x5F_add_dp_gn.hdf'
watermark_extraction.save_weights(WEIGHTS_FNAME, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Hi. Please add the code you tried and describe further what exactly didnt work as expected.

Comment: as you can see in the above code I used decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)
to add Gaussian noise to the output of decoder, but I am not sure it works as GN that we used in Matlab or if I want to attack the output of layer I can use this noise layer because in keras blog said this layer only works in training so I do not know what will happen when I want to test my network. could guide me?

Comment: could you please help me? I really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake was I used the network for testing too, but I should divide the network into two parts and then used an image with Gaussian attack as input, not the same network. two new networks with the same structure and learned weights.